# How to pass req.params to a callback function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on my Node.js project using Express. I have tried to pull data using NPM request package and the given url and pass an anonymous callback function to make use of a resulting JSON file.

I did not have any issue with the code below. I have tried, however, to change the get-endpoint to /articles/:articleid in order to res.send() an individual, different article depending on req.params.articleid sent by a browser.

Here are things I have tried: 1. I have tried to pull out the variable newsData out of the callback function... (I am not quite sure how to pull it right though. I keep getting a log saying newsData is undefined.) 2. I have tried to pass req.params.articleid to the callback function so that it can do its work inside.

Can you please help me out? Thanks!

```
app.get('/articles/:articleid', function(req, res) {
    // I was trying to declare a variable so that I can pull the data out to 
    // the variable... is it plausible?
    var newsData = {}; 
    var url = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=9667e9e4e1de495ba09b4b875dff8039";
    var info = '';        

    // var data = request({ }, function() { return newsData }); It did not return 
    // the newsData to the variable but the request object. Is there any way I can 
    // get the data in this way? 
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            newsData = body; //JSON data
            newsData.articles.forEach(function(article) {
                info += `
                <article>
                    <h2>${article.title}</h2>
                    <span>Published at ${article.publishedAt}</span>
                    <p>${article.description}</p>
                    <a href="${article.url}"><img src="${article.urlToImage}"></img></a>
                </article>
                `
            })
            res.send(`
                    <h1>Techcrunch</h1>
                    <div class="articles">
                        <article>
                            <h2>${article.title}</h2>
                            <span>Published at ${article.publishedAt}</span>
                            <p>${article.description}</p>
                            <a href="${article.url}"><img src="${article.urlToImage}"></img></a>
                        </article>
                    </div>
           `);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes shure But why? Why not simply do that in the callback?

Comment: I have a hard time with req.params.articleid reaching within the callback. I just do not understand how. The console keeps saying it is undefined when I try.

Comment: @hoeey for that you must do app.get("/articles/:articelId",...)

Comment: Yes I did so. my question is due to variable scoping, I cannot find a way to pass req.params to my callback function where the json data is run through the Foreach loop.

Comment: its in scope. No need to pass etc. Have a look at closures...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the body from request callback with JSON.parse(body) and try it.I have the following working code sample

```
    var app = require('express')();
var request = require('request');

app.get('/',function
(req,res){
  var url = 'http://www.swapi.co/api/people/1';
  request(url,function(error,response,body){
    var jsonRes = JSON.parse(body);// This is the response from Endpoint containing the object of results
    console.log(typeof jsonRes);
     console.log('error:', error);
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
    console.log(jsonRes.name);
    res.send(`
      <strong>Name: </strong> <p> ${jsonRes.name}</p><br>
      <strong>Height: </strong> <p> ${jsonRes.height}</p> <br>
      <strong>Mass: </strong> <p> ${jsonRes.mass}</p>
      `);
  })
})

app.listen(4000);
```